# Why does this only return the first results?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a forum, and am currently trying to display the front page (with all of the sections, forums and latest threads).
For some reason, with the code below, it only returns the first results. Any help?

PHP:

```
<?php
  $sects = "SELECT * FROM forum_cats WHERE parent=0 ORDER BY pos ASC";
  $cats = "SELECT * FROM forum_cats WHERE `parent`='%s' ORDER BY pos ASC"; //PARENT = SECT
  $threads = "SELECT count(*) AS total FROM forum_posts WHERE `parent`='%s'"; //PARENT = FORUM
  $lastthread = "SELECT * FROM forum_posts WHERE `parent`='%s' AND `type`='thread' ORDER BY `posted` DESC LIMIT 1";
  // --
  $sects = $db->query($sects);
  while($sect = $sects->fetch_assoc()):
    $section = $sect["id"];
?>

<table class="forum-section">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="6" class="forum-sec-title"><a title="<?php echo $sect["description"]; ?>" href="#forum/<?php echo $section; ?>"><?php echo $sect["title"]; ?></a></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="forum-cats">
      <th class="forum-cat-icon"><!-- Icon --></th>
      <th class="forum-cat-forum">Forum</th>
      <th class="forum-cat-threads">Threads</th>
      <th class="forum-cat-lastpost">Last Post</th>
    </tr>

<?php
    $cats = $db->query(sprintf($cats, $section));
    while ($cat = $cats->fetch_assoc()):
      $threads = $db->query(sprintf($threads, $cat['id']));
      $threads = $threads->fetch_assoc();
      $threads = $threads['total'];
      $lastthread = $db->query(sprintf($lastthread, $cat['id']));
      $lastthread = $lastthread->fetch_assoc();
?>
    <tr>
      <td class="forum-icon"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></td>
      <td><span class="forum-title"><a href="#forum/<?php echo $cat['id']; ?>"><?php echo $cat['title']; ?></a></span><span class="forum-desc"><?php echo $cat['description']; ?></span></td>
      <td class="forum-threads"><?php echo $threads; ?></td>
      <?php if ($threads != null) : ?>
      <td class="forum-lastinfo">
        <span class="forum-lastinfo-name"><a href="#forum/post/<?php echo $lastthread['id']; ?>"><?php echo $lastthread['title']; ?></a></span>
        <span class="forum-lastinfo-date" title="<?php echo $lastthread['posted']; ?>"><?php echo time_elapsed_string($lastthread['posted']); ?></span>
        <span class="forum-lastinfo-user">by <a href="#user/<?php echo $lastthread['author']; ?>">User</a></span>
      </td>
      <?php else: ?>
      <td class="forum-lastinfo">
        <span class="forum-lastinfo-name">No posts</span>
      </td>
      <?php endif; ?>
    </tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

MySQL database (forum_cats):

[image: mysql database]

Only posting the forum_cats table, because it's the only part with the problem.

Comment: You used every where fetch->assoc. please  use fetch->array. and then while loop to get your desired result

Comment: @anantkumarsingh - aren't they both just different ways of accessing the same data? If it doesn't work with assoc, it won't work with array

Comment: The use of `sprintf()` to populate parameters may be risky - use `prepare()` and `execute()` instead.

Comment: @halfer one problem is, I tried the same code before, except without sprintf - everything was defined on-the-spot, but sadly that didn't help. I'll try once more to prepare though.

Comment: OK, well get it working as it is, commit it to version control, then try prepare/execute. You can always ask a new question if you get stuck.

Comment: @halfer that fixed it, thanks. I actually forgot about preparing, silly me.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `%s` so you probably want

`$cats = "SELECT * FROM forum_cats WHERE parent LIKE'%s' ORDER BY pos ASC";`

This will return you all results ending with the letter `s`

While `parent = '%s'` will return the rows whose `parent` value is exactly equal to `%s`

Comment: I assume that the string is being fed into a `printf` somewhere, so the `%s` will be substituted with an actual string.

Comment: @andrewsi u might be right ... but I dont see that query being run in the code above